# When compiling PostGIS from source, how does PostGIS determine which components to install?

Tags: postgis, ubuntu, compile

I am trying to compile the latest PostGIS 3.2.1 from source. The compilation/installation below was successful on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (resulting in a usable PostGIS):

```
./autogen.sh ; ./configure ; make; sudo make install
```

However, when compiling under the Ubuntu 22.04 beta, it's not installing *any of the extensions* including PostGIS itself, topology etc.

`grep extension` on the entire building output showed nothing. I traced the problem down to this output below with the above build commands:

```
...
for s in liblwgeom libpgcommon postgis regress raster topology  loader utils doc  deps; do \
        echo "---- Making all in ${s}"; \
        make -C ${s} all || exit 1; \
done;
...
```

In above, there should be an `extension` entry (based on 20.04 results with the same commands).

My question is:

*How does the build process determine which components to compile and install (in this case extensions)?*

*Is it determined by PGXS or the output of another config program or is it something else?*

(then how do I change the configuration to have the compiled extensions installed?).

-- Update --

As pointed out by the accepted answer, the issue is that I didn't have the `xsltproc`  tool needed by `configure.ac` in the new Ubuntu. Adding it using:

```
sudo apt install xsltproc
```

fixed the issue.

Comment: `./configure` usually takes flags to control what is built and where it is built

Comment: fyi https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt/FAQ#I_want_only_specific_packages_from_this_repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, this is obscure and I think if more people built from source we would have fixed it sooner (these days everyone gets their postgis pre-built by a packager it seems), but in configure.ac you'll find this line.

```
dnl ===========================================================================
dnl See if we have the requirements for building the extensions, namely
dnl the xlstproc tool for generating the comments SQL file.
dnl ===========================================================================
```